# How to plot values in a bar chart from a specific DataFrame column

Tags: python, dataframe

Shown below are few rows in the DataFrame and these are the columns 'Category', 'Content Rating' and 'Reviews'.

[image]

Below shown is an extract taken from a particular DataFrame column "Content Rating".

```
In: pd.value_counts(Data['Content Rating'])  #Considered the total value count from the df column

out:   A       1000
       B        918
       C        360
       D        305
       E          3
       F          1
```

And this is the extract taken to plot a bar char

```
In: a = pd.value_counts(Data['Content Rating'])
    a.plot(kind='bar')

Out:
```

[image]

I want to have the values in the bar char.

The resulting bar chart should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i, v in enumerate([x[0] for x in a.values.tolist()]):
    plt.text(v + 3, i + .25, str(v), color='blue', fontweight='bold')
```